# How would you detect the browser / device used to access your web-site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, browser, client

You have an Angular based web-site.
Say you need to have some feature only active for certain devices or browsers.
You need to identify these from your code on the client and conditionally operate your code on that basis.
How would you do that?

Comment: If possible detecting the *feature* rather than the user agent is usually the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AngularJS you might be able to use [ng-device-detector](https://github.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector).
It's an angular add-on that uses the [UserAgent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header key to detect browsers/devices and OSs.

You can easily add it with these instructions:
https://github.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector/blob/master/readme.md

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @srfmk answer, you can use the `ng-device-detector` to detect it if you want to use angularjs.

But you can also use just JavaScript in order to do it through the `navigator` object, and its properties like `navigator.userAgent` for example.

Here the documentation to the navigator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator

But coming back to your original question, usually it would be better basing the approach directly to the features. Remember that JavaScript code is executed client-side and it can be changed/altered by users.

If the feature is something crucial and related also to securities policies, the best way probably would be to get the allowed features from the server, maybe sending to the server the device info (if you need them) and getting back the list of the allowed features.

If you put just client side code as guard of that, the code can be changed and users could be able to see restricted features too.

I hope this helps.